# Fast Beacon detection not working in Android 8.1 using Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am trying to implement the fast beacon detection by David G Young as shown [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8) under Android 8.1. Fast beacon detection in this context simply means that I want the beacons to be detected even when the app is not running or is in the background, similarly how to iOS detects beacons on a hardware level once you specify the regions.

Instead of doing it from scratch I am using the latest beacon library linked on the page.

My understanding is the "Starting an App in the Background" example on [this page](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) allows the set-up of the fast beacon detection. While I can make the "Monitoring" example work (thus making sure there are not layout issues etc), I cannot for the life of me make the fast beacon detection work. In fact, I believe the example on the page is incorrect, since it sets up the regionBootstrap without any filtering. As the blog page explains, Android 8.1 requires a filter in order to work. However, even adding a UUID filter (and using an iBeacon layout), it will not trigger whatsoever:

```
regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new Region("BackgroundRegion", Identifier.parse("e1234460-beac-acda-acda-adaaacdadded"), null, null));
```

Again, the exact same is working when using monitoring, so it cannot be related to the UUID or layout.

Setting up the RegionBootstrap, I do see that it's calling the didDetermineStateForRegion event once, but afterwards it's dead silence.
My understanding is that in case of issues, it should at least launch a JobScheduler that runs the scan, but this never seems to happen. In fact, looking at "adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler" I see zero active jobs.

This is the code that I have in the onCreate() function of the App class:

```
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    if (beaconManager.isAnyConsumerBound()) return;

    for (Region region : beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
        Timber.e("ACTIVELY MONITORED BEACON REGION: " + region.getUniqueId() + " --> STOPPING MONITORING");
        try {
            beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25")); //Kontakt.io iBeacon
    beaconManager.setDebug(true);

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new Region("BackgroundRegion", Identifier.parse(beaconUUID), null, null));
```

with the following to act on the events:

```
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Timber.e("BACKGROUND BEACON EVENT: ENTERED BOOTSTRAP REGION");
    regionBootstrap.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Timber.e("BACKGROUND BEACON EVENT: EXITED BOOTSTRAP REGION");
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    Timber.e("BACKGROUND BEACON EVENT: SWITCH");
}
```

and the corresponding log (filtered on "beacon"):

```
03-02 17:11:04.805 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=ZERO_POWER, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 1 filters, 0 clients, callingClientName=Places]
03-02 17:11:04.916 2661-15249/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: No beacon scan available - ignoring candidates.
03-02 17:11:05.369 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app I/BeaconManager: BeaconManager started up on pid 15282 named 'com.xxxxx.app' for application package 'com.xxxxx.app'.  isMainProcess=true
03-02 17:11:05.374 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
03-02 17:11:05.402 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app E/App: ACTIVELY MONITORED BEACON REGION: BackgroundRegion --> STOPPING MONITORING
03-02 17:11:05.455 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
03-02 17:11:05.458 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: This consumer is not bound.  Binding now: org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap$InternalBeaconConsumer@6051fc0
03-02 17:11:05.458 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: Not starting beacon scanning service. Using scheduled jobs
03-02 17:11:05.460 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: callback packageName: com.xxxxx.app
03-02 17:11:05.482 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanState: Temp file is /data/user/0/com.xxxxx.app/files/android-beacon-library-scan-state-temp
03-02 17:11:05.482 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanState: Perm file is /data/user/0/com.xxxxx.app/files/android-beacon-library-scan-state
03-02 17:11:05.491 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanJobScheduler: Scheduling ScanJob (job:1/com.xxxxx.app/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob) to run every 300000 millis
03-02 17:11:05.492 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app E/App: BACKGROUND BEACON EVENT: SWITCH
03-02 17:11:05.493 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: updating background flag to true
03-02 17:11:05.493 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: updating scan period to 10000, 300000
03-02 17:11:05.507 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanState: Temp file is /data/user/0/com.xxxxx.app/files/android-beacon-library-scan-state-temp
03-02 17:11:05.507 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanState: Perm file is /data/user/0/com.xxxxx.app/files/android-beacon-library-scan-state
03-02 17:11:05.511 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/ScanJobScheduler: Scheduling ScanJob (job:1/com.xxxxx.app/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob) to run every 310000 millis
03-02 17:11:05.512 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/BeaconManager: consumer count is now: 1
03-02 17:11:05.512 15282-15282/com.xxxxx.app D/AppStarter: Waiting for BeaconService connection
03-02 17:11:11.731 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Places requested to stop scan
03-02 17:11:11.734 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.
.....
03-02 17:34:29.700 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Places requested to stop scan
03-02 17:34:29.702 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.
03-02 17:35:17.683 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=ZERO_POWER, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 1 filters, 0 clients, callingClientName=Places]
03-02 17:35:17.755 2661-26507/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: No beacon scan available - ignoring candidates.
03-02 17:35:30.769 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Places requested to stop scan
03-02 17:35:30.772 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.
03-02 17:38:10.981 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=LOW_LATENCY, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 6 filters, 2 clients, callingClientName=Nearby]
03-02 17:38:10.987 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Stopping scan on delegate scanner. BT state: 12
03-02 17:38:10.989 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Resetting - new scanner available: true
03-02 17:38:10.989 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: 'L' hardware scan: 8 filters, scanMode=2, reportdelay=0, callback type=1, #clients=2, workSource=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms, 10115 com.android.chrome}
03-02 17:38:10.990 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Starting scan on OS scanner. BT state: 12
03-02 17:38:11.301 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=ZERO_POWER, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 1 filters, 0 clients, callingClientName=Places]
03-02 17:38:11.388 2661-26963/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: No beacon scan available - ignoring candidates.
03-02 17:38:15.016 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=ZERO_POWER, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 6 filters, 2 clients, callingClientName=Nearby]
03-02 17:38:15.019 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Stopping scan on delegate scanner. BT state: 12
03-02 17:38:15.022 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Resetting - new scanner available: true
03-02 17:38:15.023 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: 'L' hardware scan: 2 filters, scanMode=0, reportdelay=0, callback type=1, #clients=3, workSource=WorkSource{}
03-02 17:38:15.024 2661-5362/? I/BeaconBle: Starting scan on OS scanner. BT state: 12
03-02 17:38:26.074 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Places requested to stop scan
03-02 17:38:26.076 2661-2661/? I/BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.
```

I can't say for sure, but my gutfeeling is that something should happen right after "AppStarter: Waiting for BeaconService connection", e.g. I am expecting a connection.

Any help would be appreciated. A fully working example for fast beacon detection/launching in the background in Android 8.1 would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on here without seeing more of the code.  I'd be curious to see more of the code in the App class before the setup of the RegionBootstrap including the scope of that variable.  Is there any other code that could be executing in parallel in the same app?  From the log lines, it seems some other thread must be calling `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)`.   There *is* a reference app that shows how this fast detection is done [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference).  I'd be curious to know if that works for you.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for coming back to me. 

Just FYI, I saw the reference app before, but since it was mostly referencing Android M and even the overview was talking about API 23, I thought it was outdated. It would help if you add a quick note in the overview showing the latest version of support.

I also tested the reference app, where the JobScheduling works. Turns out that the Kontakt.io SDK doesn't play well with your library. It also seemed that using only your library, but doing both, monitoring and regionBootstrap won't launch the JobScheduler, but I need to test this more.

Comment: There still seemed to be issues with the fast beacon detection, even when I got it to work. There were no other beacons with the same UUID around, so the 15 minute delay shouldn't be an issue, right? I was filtering on the UUID. Would you by chance have a recommendation for EddyStone beacons that support EID and broadcast an iBeacon frame for waking up iOS apps? I found that a lot of beacon manufacturers try to push their own SDK, and it's really not helpful because they don't keep up with the latest developments like you. Thank you!

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't matter which uuid the beacons are transmitting.  If they are around and they match one of the formats you are looking for, they will cause the 15 minute delay.  (There are good reasons for this I am happy to discuss elsewhere so not to sidetrack the topic.)   Radius Networks RadBeacon X4 devices transmit both EID and iBeacon.